# VS Code - how to show folding symbols all the time?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-folding

Before I moved to VS Code I was using Notepad++ (which sadly has no native support for Linux). I've been editing a lot of JSON lately and folding is something that I missed. Imagine my surprise when I searched in the settings and in the **Editor** section saw:

```
// Controls whether the editor has code folding enabled
"editor.folding": true,
```

But there were no folding symbols to be seen. So today I move my mouse near the place where line numbers are displayed and imagine my surprise when the folding symbols appeared.

While I do appreciate the thought to save some space by hiding these I would actually prefer to set VS Code in such a way that folding symbols are displayed whenever folding is possible.

PS: I know I can use [hot keys](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding) to do that.

Comment: This feature doesn't seem to exist. You can vote for it in issues: [vscode issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3911).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Yes, I will definitely vote for it. :)

Comment: I accepted marking this question as a duplicate however I will also edit the answer given by @smhrjn since it's missing a crucial piece of information namely the version of VS code when this feature was introduced namely the *1.13*.