# Show always collapse sections of code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Collapse/expand controls appears you need to **mouse over** the area just to the right of the line numbers.
Is way show this section **always** without **mouse over the area**?Is this feature supported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vs-code-how-to-show-folding-symbols-all-the-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042423/vs-code-how-to-show-folding-symbols-all-the-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make the code folding icons always show in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476212/make-the-code-folding-icons-always-show-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to bottom left side and click settings icon.
2. Click settings and find ' "editor.showFoldingControls": "mouseover" '
3. Write "always" instead of "mouseover"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Or you can add in ***settings.json***

```
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always"
```